# How to keep static mesh in sync with skeletal mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, shrinkwrap

I'm brand new to blender and I'm trying to essentially use a static mesh with armor as a second skin for arms, legs, torso etc. of a skeletal mesh. I started with shrinkwrap and while it worked-ish, it conformed exactly like a second skin, which distorted the shape of the armor. Next I tried using a lattice along with the static mesh, thinking that I could then play with the thickness. I couldn't, however, get a lattice that would place the static mesh all around the body segment in question.

I'm hoping someone can give me some guidance on either making the lattice work, or perhaps another way to keep, for example, the static leg mesh with armor, in sync with the skeletal mesh underneath. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Some screen of your situation or issue would be helpful. But if I understood ... Parent armor object to a bone should work or parent armor to a three point (vertex) of body as well.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many a question on armature deformation, but maybe never quite like this. Anyway, FYI more than one mesh can be controlled by the same armature with an armature deform modifier. Also, vertex groups need not blend across armor parts, I.e. you can deform robot-like parts in a realistic manner without solid bits bending.